# How to override "ignore" part of bower.json file of dependency?

Tags: bower, bower-install

I would like to use https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF in my ember project. 
I wanted to import jsPDF as dependency, therefore I started this way:

`bower install git@github.com:MrRio/jsPDF.git --save`

Unfortunately, I cannot install files from plugins directory, because `"plugins/*"` directory is ignored in bower.json file.
I have tried overriding it this way, but without success.

```
  "overrides": {
    "jspdf": {
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "libs",
        "CNAME",
        "jspdf.js",
        "examples/jspdf.PLUGINTEMPLATE.js",
        "todo.txt",
        "wscript.py",
        "build.sh",
        "test",
        "tools"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? When you install is using `bower install jspdf --save`, the whole directory will be downloaded to your `bower_components` directory. What is the problem you are facing? The plugins directory isn't downloaded in the package or what?

Comment: Yes, the plugins directory is not downloaded , because it is ignored in bower.json file in the original repo (what is understandable). I can fork this repo and create my own bower.json file with plugins inside, but I think there might exist a solution that does not require forking a repo and is more clean.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a jsPDF plugins package to bower.
You can add all the plugins via

```
bower install jsPDF-plugins --save
```